# urllib2 fetch web page

Tags: python, urllib2, fetch, web-crawler

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I'm using urllib2 to fetch many url. There is a url that sometimes comes back to me the whole html page and sometimes not. This is my code:

```
def find_html(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB;   rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14')
    page_html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

    n = string.find(page_html, "filter clearfix active")
    print "find element:",n

url = "http://it.hotels.com/ho113127/rome-cavalieri-waldorf-astoria-hotels-resorts-roma-italia/"
find_html(url)
```

Why is this happening? Where am I doing wrong?
(I do not want to use selenium for this url and I want to use urllib2)

Comment: If it is just one URL, perhaps it is that server? I doubt it is a Python or urllib2 problem..

Comment: I think is the server. With this kind of urls I have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting both 200 and 301 (`Moved Permanently`) responses from that URL, so it's a server thing.

Since `urllib2` will automatically follow the redirect, you have to check if the redirect occurred if you want to prevent processing the redirected page (which, if I understand correctly, doesn't contain the information you want):

```
...
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
if response.geturl() == url:
  // no redirect occurred
else:
  // a redirect occurred because the url has changed
```

It depends on your exact setup and intentions how you'd have to handle that (because for some URL's you might actually want to process the redirected page).

Comment: Thank you @robertklep. How do I see which code comes back to me?

Comment: I've edited my answer because I mistakenly assumed `urllib2` wouldn't handle the redirect itself.

Comment: If I use python requests I take ever 200... I don't understand...

Comment: I don't wont to handle the redirect url, I wont to handle only the original url. Why a server sometimes redirect a url and sometimes not?

Comment: Who knows :) It might be a configuration error on the server.

Comment: #robertkelp I'm sorry bat if you try with this url = "http://it.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?hotelId=113127&page=1#reviews" sometimes I get 200 and I don't get the right html. What's going on?

Comment: It might be the same (server) problem, although it's giving me 200 responses it might still not always return the same HTML for each request.